# ZFC Rbac UnauthorizedStrategy and Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework3, zfc-rbac

I read the [documentation on Strategies](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac/blob/master/docs/05.%20Strategies.md) and it seems the code below is valid at least in Zend Framework 2. Of course, I tested it.

```
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e)
{
    $t = $e->getTarget();
    $t->getEventManager()->attach(
        $t->getServiceManager()->get('ZfcRbac\View\Strategy\UnauthorizedStrategy')
    );
}
```

But when using the Zend Framework 3, it no longer works. It will show the error below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Zend\EventManager\EventManager::attach() must be callable, object given, called in /var/www/sub.domain.tld/html/module/Application/src/Module.php on line 20

So basically I am stuck right now. Can you at least point out or guide me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to ditch the `UnauthorizedStrategy` class. Basically, I copied the code from `onError` method from `UnauthorizedStrategy` class and modified to fit my needs.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    /** @var EventManager $eventManager */
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, [$this, 'onError'], 100);
}

public function onError(MvcEvent $event) {
    // Do nothing if no error or if response is not HTTP response
    if (($event->getResult() instanceof HttpResponse)
        || !($event->getResponse() instanceof HttpResponse)
    ) {
        return;
    }

    $baseModel = new ViewModel();
    $baseModel->setTemplate('layout/layout');

    $model = new ViewModel();
    $model->setTemplate('error/403');

    switch ($event->getError()) {
        case GuardInterface::GUARD_UNAUTHORIZED:
            $model->setVariable('error', GuardInterface::GUARD_UNAUTHORIZED);
            break;

        default:
            return; // If it is not unauthorized error, skip it so it will show the more appropriate errors.
    }

    $baseModel->addChild($model);
    $baseModel->setTerminal(true);

    $event->setViewModel($baseModel);

    $response = $event->getResponse() ?: new HttpResponse();
    $response->setStatusCode(403);

    $event->setResponse($response);
    $event->setResult($baseModel);

    $event->stopPropagation();
}
```